# Version mismatch between V8 binary and snapshot

Tags: php, linux, debian, v8, v8js

I have an issue related to v8, now it is unrelated to your docker image but since I have seen you being active in the space I thought you may be able to help

My setup is the following:
Debian 11
php7.2-fpm
v8 version 10.0.1
v8js checkout 6a7753a43a0840eb28cc2cea1bf92331f633b3eb

php-fpm error log (v8 error messages):

```
[12-May-2022 15:43:43.242486] WARNING: pid 20650, fpm_stdio_child_said(), line 189: [pool ***] child 20744 said into stderr: "#"
[12-May-2022 15:43:43.242491] WARNING: pid 20650, fpm_stdio_child_said(), line 189: [pool ***] child 20744 said into stderr: "# Fatal error in , line 0"
[12-May-2022 15:43:43.242494] WARNING: pid 20650, fpm_stdio_child_said(), line 189: [pool ***] child 20744 said into stderr: "# Version mismatch between V8 binary and snapshot."
[12-May-2022 15:43:43.242498] WARNING: pid 20650, fpm_stdio_child_said(), line 189: [pool ***] child 20744 said into stderr: "#   V8 binary version: 10.0.1"
[12-May-2022 15:43:43.242501] WARNING: pid 20650, fpm_stdio_child_said(), line 189: [pool ***] child 20744 said into stderr: "#    Snapshot version: 0 (candidate)"
[12-May-2022 15:43:43.242504] WARNING: pid 20650, fpm_stdio_child_said(), line 189: [***] child 20744 said into stderr: "# The snapshot consists of 10942900 bytes and contains 1 context(s)."
[12-May-2022 15:43:43.242508] WARNING: pid 20650, fpm_stdio_child_said(), line 189: [pool ***] child 20744 said into stderr: "#"
[12-May-2022 15:43:43.242511] WARNING: pid 20650, fpm_stdio_child_said(), line 189: [pool ***] child 20744 said into stderr: "#"
[12-May-2022 15:43:43.242514] WARNING: pid 20650, fpm_stdio_child_said(), line 189: [pool ***] child 20744 said into stderr: "#"
[12-May-2022 15:43:43.242517] WARNING: pid 20650, fpm_stdio_child_said(), line 189: [pool ***] child 20744 said into stderr: "#FailureMessage Object: 0x7ffebdd5b400"
[12-May-2022 15:43:43.242521] DEBUG: pid 20650, fpm_event_loop(), line 423: event module triggered 1 events
[12-May-2022 15:43:43.242593] WARNING: pid 20650, fpm_stdio_child_said(), line 189: [pool ***] child 20744 said into stderr: ""
```

Would highly appreciate any help!!

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Answer (score 2):

Something is broken in your installation. When V8 uses a snapshot, then that snapshot must be created with the exact same V8 version as the binary that tries to open it. So for example, if you created a custom snapshot, and then updated V8, then you'll have to re-create that snapshot. If you got the whole setup from somewhere else, then that other place needs to fix the packages they distribute.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Acautally I compiled v8 + v8js with php7.1 installed, but the unit tests for v8js had a 100% failure rate so I purged php7.1 and tried with php7.2 - the unit tests were successful so I assumed everything would be working - could this be the issue?

Comment: I have no idea how the dependencies and interactions between php and v8js work, so yeah, I suppose that _could_ be the issue. Another oddity is that V8 version 10.0.1 is just a random development snapshot; I'm not sure but it could be that a branched version makes a difference for snapshots, see https://v8.dev/docs/version-numbers.

Comment: Thanks, turned out the checkout version of v8 I used (10.0.1) does not work together with v8js, I used v 8.8.9 of v8 which solved my issue.